# Nano - class is public, should be declared in a file named

Tags: java, nano

I'm trying to run java in nano, on a mac. I tried to make the java class file, but run into an error: `Class.java:3: class PrintLns is public, should be declared in a file named PrintLns.java`.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrintLns {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type in a command");
        String x = scanner.nextLine();
        if (x == "Y"){
             System.out.println("You said Yes");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *should be declared in a file named PrintLns.java* - rename your java file to  PrintLns.java

Comment: `if (x == "Y")` is not how you compare Strings in java

Comment: `mv ./Class.java ./PrintLns.java`